# Running several unknown ng-repeat inside of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, loops, angularjs-ng-repeat

Lets say we have an array like this. On this example, for simplification I just added one object in the array, but let's assume it has many.

```
$scope.var = [
    {name: "John",
     surname: "Smith",
     children: [

         {name: "Phil",
          surname: "Smith",
          children: [

              {name: "Peter",
               surname: "Smith",
               children: []},

              {name: "Joe",
              surname: "Smith",
              children: [

                  {name: "Dirk",
                   surname: "Smith",
                   children: [

                       {name: "Carl",
                        surname: "Smith",
                        children: []}
                   ]
                  }
              ]
              }
          ]
         }
     ]
    }
];
```

So, has you can see, each object has an dedicated to children which is made of more objects. 
On a less conceptual manner, let's say I am doing a family tree and decided started with my grand grand grand grand grand dad. Now I want to display the name of everyone using ng-repeat.

How can I use ng repeat n times without knowing the number of n. How would I iterate a ng-repeat?

Hope I was clear about this.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Check out this: http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `recursive ng-repeat`.

<kbd>**`JSFiddle DEMO`**</kbd>

**Explanation:**

During the first `ng-repeat` the first level is taken in the object `var`, in the same tag we have an `ng-include` which will include the template we have provided (`categoryTree`), then the first level name will get populated in 
`{{ person.name }}` Then an ng-if is used, which basically checks if the level contains a children property. Important information about ng-if.

> Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new scope is created when the element is restored. The scope created within ngIf inherits from its parent scope using prototypal inheritance. An important implication of this is if ngModel is used within ngIf to bind to a javascript primitive defined in the parent scope. In this case any modifications made to the variable within the child scope will override (hide) the value in the parent scope.

Above lines were taken from [Angular ng-if Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

So the gist of what I want to say is, inside the `ng-if` tag there is another `ng-repeat` with the same variable name (`person`), So since `ng-if` creates a new scope, thus the previous variable `person` does not exist here, hence it is treated as a new variable. Hence we get the repeating div's and this process continues till the `ng-if` finally breaks when there are no more children to repeat.

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app='myApp'>
    <li ng-repeat="person in var" ng-include="'categoryTree'"></li>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="categoryTree">
    {{ person.name }}
    <ul ng-if="person.children">
        <li ng-repeat="person in person.children" ng-include="'categoryTree'">           
        </li>
    </ul>
</script>
```

**References:**

1. [AngularJS Recursive Templates](http://benfoster.io/blog/angularjs-recursive-templates)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Basically you create a template in the js file and then call it in the html file? O knew this add to be done using a controller or something